# Is this a valid interpretation of the Mean relative speed between two (Maxwell-Boltzmann) species?

Tags: physical-chemistry, reaction-control, kinetic-theory-of-gases, statistical-mechanics

In textbooks, the collision frequency $Z_{ab}$ is always given as something like:

$$Z_{ab} = n_an_b\sigma_{ab} \Bigg(\frac{8 k T}{\pi \mu}\Bigg)^{1/2}= n_an_b\sigma_{ab} \bar{C}_{rel}$$

where the reduced mass $\mu = m_am_b/(m_a+m_b)$. Given that the mean speed of a species "i" is given by $\bar{C}_i = \Big(\frac{8 k T}{\pi m_i}\Big)^{1/2}$, then, algebraically,  the first equation is equivalent to:

$$Z_{ab} = n_an_b\sigma_{ab} \sqrt{\bar{C}_a^2 + \bar{C}_b^2}$$

Is there a reason that this is not a valid interpretation of the collision frequency? I have not found a single source which presents either the collision rate $Z_{ab}$, or the mean relative speed $\bar{C}_{rel}$ in this way.

Comment: Mathematically it is the same with you definition of $C_i$.

Comment: I posted the same question on the physics forum to see if it would get any more traction. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/674124/is-this-a-valid-interpretation-of-the-mean-relative-speed-collision-rate-of-part